# Fixture in behave is not being used in a Scenario

Tags: python, bdd, fixtures, python-3.9, python-behave

I want to have a fixture in behave that will do some cleanup after a Scenario.
I am using behave 1.2.6

My code:
`my-proj/fixtures.py`

```
@fixture
def cleanup(context):
    yield
    print(f"{context: {context}")
    # Do some cleaning up
```

`my-proj/features/test.feature`

```
Feature: cleanup test

  @fixture.cleanup
  Scenario: check cleanup is working
     Given this test
      When it runs
      Then all is good
```

I followed the docs:

- https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#provide-a-fixture
- https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fixtures.html#using-a-fixture

but I am missing something as this code is not working, the fixture code is never run.

Can anyone help me understand what is the problem?
I did try to put the code from `fixtures.py` in `my-proj/features/environment.py` but had the same result, the fixture code is not running.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I add:

```
def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    if "fixture.cleanup" in scenario.tags:
        use_fixture(cleanup, context)
```

But I was wondering if it should also work without the tags condition...

Comment: Did you find any alternate ways of doing this?